# Washing machine shaking

Tags: appliances, washing-machine, washer

I've got a Maytag washing machine, model number mvwc500vw1, that is shaking pretty bad in the spin cycle. I've made sure the feet are level, replaced the suspension springs and both sets of snubber pads, though none of them seemed particularly worn. I also checked to make sure the balance ring fluid hasn't leaked out. Anything else I should check on this washer?

Here's a GIF of it shaking unloaded with the cabinet off. When the cabinet is on and there are clothes in it, the tub bangs against the cabinet and is very noisy.

[image]

Comment: Has the machine ever worked properly before? If it is a brand new machine, you may have missed one of the pegs that holds the drum in place. If it was working before but only started recently, then something inside probably broke.

Comment: It happens when overload with clothes having drastically different weight - like mixing shirts, soxes with bath towels, and/or heavy jackets, when spin, it tends to be heavy on one side of the drum that causes it to rob against the wall. When the noise starts, readjust the load evenly, then it should be fine.

Comment: @Nelson, It's not a new machine, it came with the house when I moved in. It was fine for a few years, but in the last several months started shaking and got increasingly worse.

Comment: @r13, the machine shakes every time we run it, no mater the size or balance of the load. It even shakes when run empty, though not as severe as when loaded.

Comment: If you don't want to replace it, maybe it's time to call for service.

Comment: Check out https://www.partselect.com/Repair/Washer/Shakes-Moves/ and pick your battle. If you don't want to deal with it then call Maytag and they will gladly send out a certified repair tech at your own cost. Since the washer is likely out of warranty this will ultimately be your cost to bear.